# Emacs - Remove line number from mode-line

Tags: emacs, customization

I already have line-numbers on the side so having the line-number in the mode-line is redundant. How do I get rid of it?

Comment: See the variable `mode-line-format`.

Comment: The following link contains some nice ideas for customizing the `mode-line-format`:  http://amitp.blogspot.com/2011/08/emacs-custom-mode-line.html

Comment: @lawlist the sad thing is, I just installed `nyan-mode`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the emacs wiki on [mode lines](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ModeLineConfiguration).

You'd toggle this on or off by adding a line to your `.emacs` file:

```
(line-number-mode 0)
```

or (to enable):

```
(line-number-mode 1)
```